# Your security settings have blocked an application from running with an out-of-date or expired version of Java

Tags: java

Greetings .

I've encountered a Java Error ,which is actually giving me a nightmare .

It says :

" Application Blocked by Security Settings "

" Your security settings have blocked an application from running with an out-of-date or expired version of Java "

Java Version : 1.7_25 ( Recommended for my work and not an old one i believe)

Workaround i have performed (which did not work) :

1. Lowered Security Level to Medium.
2. Cleared Browser Cache and Cookies.
3. Checked a few settings in the Advanced Tab of the Java Control Panel like :

> General : Allow user to grant permissions to signed content.
>
> Java Cache was also cleared.
>
> Even after performing the above workarounds, one after other, the issue doesn't go and there is no exceptions site list in the security tab either(just for information).

Majority of the issues related to the error would go after the security level is lowered to medium. But mine doesn't.

Hope some one could help me out.
Shall be ever grateful.

Thank you !

AK

Comment: Lower the security level to lowest and try again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

> "[Java 1.7.0_25 is] recommended for my work and not an old one i believe".

Unfortunately, your belief is incorrect.   As of now (when you asked the Question), Java 1.7.0_u25 is over a year old, and there have been 4 security-relevant releases to Java 1.7 since that release.

In fact, you probably don't have any option apart from upgrading ... if you want to use that application via your web browser.  The version checks cannot be overridden (AFAIK) for Java applications launched via your web browser and/or using Java Web Start.  This is a good thing too.

---

So how does this jive with your "work recommendation"?

You need to talk to your system admins, or security people, or whoever made that recommendation.  Under normal circumstances, it is bad to use an out-of-date version of Java, especially if you enable it in your web browser.  It leaves you open to all sorts of security exploits.

It may turn out that there is a sound reason for this "recommendation"; for example a compatibility issue for some other Java-based apps that they need to support.  If that is the case, you have a hard choice to make:

- You could upgrade to the latest Java 1.7 release and risk not being able to use applications that (really) require an older release of Java.
- You could not upgrade, and give up on the idea of using the app that is giving you problems.
- You install a second web browser, and configure on to use the latest Java release, and the other to use the older "recommended" release.  This could be messy, but (at least) Java is designed to allow you to have multiple JRE or JDK installs on your system simultaneously.

---

> ... but my application(on which i am working, unfortunately supports up to this version (i.e. 7_25).

Developing an application that only runs on old versions of Java doesn't seem like a good business strategy.

But assuming there is a good reason, you should be able to install BOTH 1.7.0_25 AND a later version on your system ... and use one for your development work and the other for running web-based applications.

Or if that isn't appealing, then use different virtual machines, or different physical machines for doing the different types of work that you need to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I understand that the Java version (1.7.0_u25) is not the latest, but my application(on which i am working, unfortunately supports upto this version(i,e 7_25) , Therefore, the option of upgrading my Java is at a standstill.
Also, the browser we use is IE 8 ,and apart from this , this configuration is working for the rest,while im the one facing the issue alone :(
any other way is deeply apreciated .
Thanks for your time and Patience.I totally appreciate it.
Regards,
a.k

Answer (score 2):

"Your security settings have blocked an application from running with an **out-of-date or expired** version of Java"

Java Version : **1.7_25** ( Recommended for my work and not an old one i believe)

From [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html):

> Java SE 7u67
>   This release addresses a regression introduced in the most recent security update. Oracle strongly recommends that all Java SE 7 users upgrade to this release.

You are **not** on the latest release for version 1.7.

There have been **7** releases since 1.7.25.

Answer (score 1):

Actual problem can be not an outdated Java but applet jar sign/manifest/jnlp.

Workaround:

1.Install latest JRE from Oracle site

2.Uncheck "Enable Java content in browser" in old java/jre (javacpl.exe)

3.Make sure that applet correctly works with latest JRE

4.Uncheck "Enable Java content in browser" in latest JRE and check it in your old JRE

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I reduced security level from high to medium and allowed to run the application at risk, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding the site URL to the Security Exception Site list without lowering your overall security level.